# Authentication of facebook in your website using php graph sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have made a login authentication in my website using php graph SDK and made a Facebook developer app to link it. Whenever I try to login, it fetches the data and stores it in the database. The issue is if any other person tries to log in it shows an error

> "Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app since we are
> updating additional details for this app. Please try again later."

index.php is

```php
    <?php //session_destroy(); ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Login with Facebook using PHP and MySQL | Ingenious Gurus </title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     
    </head>
    
    <?php include('config.php'); ?>
    <?php include('oauth-user.php'); ?>
    
    
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
    
                    <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                    <hr/>
                    <form class="form-vertical" action="" method="POST">
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email_address" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter your email address" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['email_cookie'])){ echo $_COOKIE['email_cookie'] ; } ?>">
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter your password"  value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['pass_cookie'])){ echo $_COOKIE['pass_cookie'] ; } ?>" >
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="Yes">
                            Remember Me
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="LoginButton">
                                Login
                            </button>
                             
                        </div>
    
                    </form>    
                    
                     
                    <hr/>
    
            <?php
            //If no $accessToken is set then user should log in first
            if(isset($accessToken)) {
                if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
                    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
                } else {
                    // Put short-lived access token in session
                    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
                    
                    // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
                    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
                    
                    if(!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
                        //Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
                        try {
                            $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
                            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
                        } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                            echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
                            exit;
                        }
                    }           
                }
                
                // Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
                if(isset($_GET['code'])){
                    header('Location: ./');
                }
                
                
                // Getting user facebook profile info
                try {
                    $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture');
                    $fbUserData = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
                    
                    //Ceate an instance of the OauthUser class
                    $oauth_user_obj = new OauthUser();
                    $userData = $oauth_user_obj->verifyUser($fbUserData);
                } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
                    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                    session_destroy();
                    // Redirect user back to app login page
                    header("Location: ./");
                    exit;
                } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
                    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                    session_destroy();
                    // Redirect user back to app login page
                    header("Location: ./");
                    exit;
                }
            
            
                // Get logout url
                //$logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl($accessToken, 'http://localhost/mit-demos/facebook-login/logout.php');
                
            
                
            } else {
                // Get login url
                $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl);
                echo '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($loginUrl).'"><img class="login_image" src="fblogin-btn.png"></a>';
            }
        ?>
           
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

config.php code

```php
    session_start();
    require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';
    
    // By Ingenious Gurus:  https://ingeniousgurus.com
    
    // Include required libraries
    use Facebook\Facebook;
    use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
    use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
    
    $redirectUrl   = 'https://afrahbladi.com/nlogin/index.php'; //Callback URL
    $permissions = array('email');  //Optional permissions
    
    $fb = new Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'fb_app_id ', // Replace fb_app_id with your app id
      'app_secret' => 'fb_app_secret ',  // Replace fb_app_secret with your app secret key
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
      ]);
    
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
        $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
    }
    
    try {
        if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
            $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
        } else {
            $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        }
    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
```

oauth.php

```php
    class OauthUser {
        
        private $host          = "localhost";
        private $username      = "username      ";
        private $password      = "password      ";
        private $database_name = "database_name ";
        private $table         = 'users';
        private $db;
        
        function __construct(){
            // Connect to the MySQL database
            $this->db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database_name);
            if($this->db->connect_error){
                die("Failed to connect with MySQL database: " . $this->db->connect_error);
            }
        }
        
        function verifyUser($userInfo) {
            
            $qry_body = "   `oauth_provider` = 'facebook',
                                `oauth_id`       = '".$userInfo['id']."',
                                `name`           = '".$userInfo['name']."',
                                `first_name`     = '".$userInfo['first_name']."', 
                                `last_name`      = '".$userInfo['last_name']."', 
                                `email`          = '".$userInfo['email']."', 
                                `picture`        = '".$userInfo['picture']['url']."'";
    
                            //exit();
    
            
            $select_qry = "select * from `users` where `oauth_provider`='facebook' and `oauth_id`= '".$userInfo['id']."'";
            $res = $this->db->query($select_qry);
            if($res->num_rows > 0) {
                //Update user details if it is already exists in the table
                $qry = "update ".$this->table." set ".$qry_body." WHERE `oauth_provider` = 'facebook' AND `oauth_id` = '".$userInfo['id']."'";
            } else {
                //Insert into table if user not exists in the table
                $qry = "insert into ".$this->table." set ".$qry_body.", `created_at`='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'";        
            }
    
            $this->db->query($qry);
            $_SESSION['user_is_login']     = true;
            $_SESSION['user_id']      = $userInfo['id'];
            $_SESSION['user_name']    = $userInfo['name'];
            $_SESSION['user_fname']   = $userInfo['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['user_lname']   = $userInfo['last_name'];
            $_SESSION['user_email']   = $userInfo['email'];
            $_SESSION['user_picture'] = $userInfo['picture']['url'];
            header('location:welcome.php');
            exit();
        }
        
    }
```

in public_html I have made nlogin folder in which thsese files are placed and also php graph sdk

Additionally here it´s:

1. Basic settings of facebook developer app: [Facebook developer app
   basic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7DFx.png)
2. Login settings: [Faceebook developer app login
   settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc37d.png).

Comment: There is a note on top of that second screenshot, telling you what to do.

Comment: @CBroe  I am only accessing profile image, email and name, is  any need to make it buissness  authenticated?

Comment: not any person can give its solution I m very depressed due to it, cant find any solution from Chatgpt and Youtube tries everything